# JQuery UI resizable/draggable loses 'grip' when moving on top of video element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, youtube-api, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a page with an embedded youtube video, and I'm trying to implement a custom overlay where you can define areas using a resizable and draggable `<div>` (using JQuery UI).

When dragging the `<div>` in other areas of the screen, it's perfectly responsive, but when over the video (embedded using the IFrame API, incase it matters), if you move the mouse at anything other than a crawl, it will regularly 'lose its grip' on the resize handles or the move handle.  This is the case in both IE and Chrome.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MfZes/1/ (draggable box is below the youtube frame)

Does anyone know why this is, or if it's avoidable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fwiw, my best guess is that when the mouse pointer briefly gets 'ahead' of the element's outer edge during resizing, the mouse events are getting caught by the video element behind it and not propagated back up to the overlay div.  Not sure if there's anything that can be done about that.

Comment: I've never needed to do it but you may be able to replace the video element with a static placeholder (eg. an img) while resizing. This is a bit messy but may be your best bet ... if it works.

Comment: Events will not be propagated by the iframe embed, this is due to browser security and works as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done this before.

You can hook onto the dragstart, resizestart, dragstop and resizestop events of jquery ui's resizeable and draggable plugins.

Put the video in a container div. Alongside the video, insert another div which will act as an overlay. Set the width and height to 100%, position it absolutely and set the display to hidden.

When the resize/drag start events fire, show the overlay div. When they stop, hide it. (You need to hide it as you still want to be able to interact with the video when you're not resizing or dragging.

Comment: This is so wonderfully helpful, I am surprised not to find it anywhere in the jQuery UI documentation. It works for any div, not just videos. Great tip!

Comment: You save my day ;0)  I have same issue with an iframe today and your tips was running well. I also found good simple way to how implement the overlay you indicated here : https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with hover on canvas:

```
$('.DraggableDiv').draggable({
    start : function() {
        var d = document.createElement('div');
        $(d).addClass('canvas_shadow');
        $('.canvasContainer').append(d);
    },
    stop : function() {
        $( ".canvas_shadow" ).remove();
});
```

add css for .canvas_shadow:

```
.canvas_shadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.1;
  z-index: 80;
}
```